# How to convert JsonArray from Gson to stream

Tags: java, json, java-8, gson, java-stream

We are using `JsonArray` from `Gson` instead of `JSONArray`. So, we are facing issue to convert `JsonArray` to `parallelStream`. How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
Stream<JsonElement> stream = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), true);
```